# Review Failure - on Must be improved for deleted question

Tags: support, triage

Can anyone explain why this would be a review failure in Triage on clicking on Must Be Improved??

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7213776

The question has been deleted, but no obvious reason for the deletion.

So I don't think this should be a failure for someone clicking Should be Improved.

Comment: That certainly is odd. It's not a great question as-is, but it *could* have been salvaged if the OP had been given a chance to edit in the necessary information. But, having been deleted by a moderator a mere nine minutes after it was posted - for no apparent reason - that was not possible.

Comment: In fact it was deleted 20 seconds after @reporter edited it.  So maybe before the edit it was really bad.  But I can't see what the original question looked like due to it being deleted.

Comment: The edit was... not that significant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So... There was an inexplicable link to a website in that post, purportedly a link to an image but... not one.

That attracted a spam flag. Which was validated by the deletion.

I don't *think* it was actually meant as spam though; I think perhaps the author was just really bad at linking to images. Not 100% on that, but I'll give him the benefit of the doubt for now.

I've cleared the spam flag and lifted your review ban.